# Find newest Revisions of Entities where timestamp is less than x

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate-envers, spring-data-envers

I have a max timestamp that I pass to my backend and I want to return the newest versions of the Entities that have a timestamp that is less than the passed one.
The passed timestamp in my example is 180. I've kept the numbers low so that it is easier to visualize.

This is a combination of a horizontal and a vertical Query and I'm not sure how I can achieve that.

The desired result:

[image: painting of the result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be achieved with the following:

```java
public List<Book> getBooksByMaxTimestamp(Date date) {
    String formattedDate = simpleDateFormat.format(date);
    System.out.println("Less than " + formattedDate);

    AuditQuery maxRevisionNumberQuery = auditReader.createQuery().forRevisionsOfEntity(Book.class, true, false);
     
    maxRevisionNumberQuery.add(AuditEntity.revisionProperty("timestamp").le(date.getTime()));
    maxRevisionNumberQuery.addProjection(AuditEntity.revisionNumber().max());
    int maxRevisionNumber = (int) maxRevisionNumberQuery.getSingleResult();

    AuditQuery auditQuery = auditReader.createQuery().forEntitiesAtRevision(Book.class, maxRevisionNumber);
    return auditQuery.getResultList();
}
```

First we get the max revision number that is in that range and after that we use that number to get the entities that we want.